# StringReader Peek() with more steps ahead in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am using `StringReader Peek()` in C# (for my lexer).

Is it possible to have an option for more steps ahead?
For example:

```cs
var input = "Sample";
var reader = new StringReader(input);

// new Peek() functionality
var result = reader.Peek(3);
```

Then I get the `result` as following:

```
// ['S','a','m']
```

For now, `Peek()` just supports one character, Is it possible to extend this functionality?
If the number was more than the rest of the string just return what left

```cs
var result = reader.Peek(10);

// ['S','a','m', 'p','l','e']
```

I am just looking for extending `StringReader` I am aware of the other approaches.

Comment: `I am using StringReader Peek()` - [why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640)?

Comment: for a lexer, processing char by char

Comment: Read and move the stream's position back?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: StringReader is not supposed to be extended, so I believe the only option is implementing your own string reader based on TextReader.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need the StringReader, but your "peek" could be done by just using Linq:

```
var input = "Sample";
var peek = input.Take(3).ToArray();
```

`peek` should now be `['S', 'a', 'm']`. The [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-5.0) extension method will take only as many as there are if you give a number greater than the number of actual elements, just as you want.

Comment: Well, if you give up the stream (and the non-consuming semantics of `Peek`), then it's just `input[..3]`.

Comment: No, I just need to extend StringReader. I am working on a lexer.